# How do I make a hamburger Menu in sass. (Ive tried tutorials and nothing worked)

Tags: sass, responsive, hamburger-menu

Ive tried all sorts of tutorials and then all seems to include this code.

```
<span class = ""> <i class=""><i/> <i class=""><i/> </span>
```

This dosen't seem to work,
Ive also tried this

```
<a href ="#" class="hamburger><i class=""></i> </a>
```

It dosent seem to work. Please help, Thank you so much!.

IM using this rn

```
<nav class="navbar">
                <div class="logo-box"><img src="../logos/foschini.png" class="logo"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Hire an Engineer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hiring</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="hamburger">
                    <i class="bar">Hire</i>
                    <i class="bar">Hiring</i>
                    <i class="bar">Plans</i>
                    <i class="bar">About us</i>
                </span>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is what I used:

scss:

```
$primary-color: #ffd000;

#SideMenuTrigger {
    position: fixed;

    right: 10em;
    top: 50%;

    transform: translateY(-50%);

    transition: right 200ms;

    width: 3.5em;
    height: 3em;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;

    span {
      position: absolute;
      height: 18%;
      background-color: $primary-color;
      width: 100%;
      transition: width 200ms, transform 200ms, opacity 200ms;
      transition-timing-function: ease-in;
      pointer-events: none;
      right: 0;
      opacity: 1;

      &:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0;
        transform-origin: bottom right;
        width: 90%;
      }

      &:nth-child(2) {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        width: 70%;
      }

      &:nth-child(3) {
        bottom: 0;
        transform-origin: top right;
        width: 60%;
      }
    }

    &:hover {
      span {
        &:nth-child(1) {
          width: 100%;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
          width: 50%;
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
          width: 65%;
        }
      }
    }

    &.is-open {
      right: 2em;

      span {
        &:nth-child(1) {
          width: 100%;
          transform: rotateZ(-42deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
          width: 100%;
          transform: translate(20px, -50%);
          opacity: 0;
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
          width: 100%;
          transform: translateY(21%) rotateZ(42deg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}%
```

html:

```html
<button id="SideMenuTrigger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</button>
```

if the menu is active add "is-open" class to button

Comment: it dosent seem to work. It just displays a long gray button that dosent do anything...

Comment: @woopwoop did you put it directly in the body?